# How to use a custom validation function for a QCompleter in a QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox, qcompleter

I have a string matching function to be used for searching for names that is more advanced than `QString::contains()` (e. g. when you search for "mueller", it will match "Müller").

I'd like to use this function to search inside a `QComboBox`. The default completion almost does what I need: If I do

```
combobox->setEditable(true);
combobox->setInsertPolicy(QComboBox::NoInsert);
combobox->completer()->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
```

and type some text in the `QComboBox`'s lineedit, the popup pops up, only showing entries starting what has been typed.

This is what I want, but I would like the `QCompleter` to evaluate matches using my search function rather than the `QString::startsWith()` that is apparently used here (and setting the mode to `Qt::MatchContains` is better but still not sufficient).

Is there any way to customize the completer's search function?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Create a custom model and implement your search using the [`QSortProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterRegExp-prop)

Comment: Disclaimer: Not tested. Can you not use `QComboBox::setCompleter` with a custom completer like in this example (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#basic-usage)? Looks like you can use your search function, populate a `QStringList` with all the suggestions and then set it for your `QComboBox`.

Comment: from what I understand you, you want that if the items in the QCombobox are: {"alpha", "omega", "omicron", "zeta"}, and you enter "m" in the QComboBox you should show "omega" and " omicron ", am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but that would be achieveable with the default implementation/behavior. My matching function also handles diacritics, German Umlauts and so on, and also does match e. g. "John Doe" with the searchb term "doe john". Therefore, I can't use the default matching method, but need to use my custom function.

Comment: @Azeem: The possible suggestions are not the problem, as all possible values are already added to the `QComboBox`. The problem is how to choose the possible values matching an entered string, as the matching functions that `QCompleter` offers are not sufficient (actually, I check multiple different versions of both the search term and the possible completions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an own `QCompleter` and set it for the `QComboBox`'s `QLineEdit`. The completer does not use the combobox's model, but an own one, which is filled with data everytime the entered text changes.

Can be done as follows:

```
m_matchingNames = new QStringListModel(this);
m_nameCompleter = new QCompleter(m_matchingNames, this);
m_nameCompleter->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
m_playersSelect->setEditable(true);
m_playersSelect->setInsertPolicy(QComboBox::NoInsert);
m_playersSelect->setCompleter(0);
m_playersSelect->lineEdit()->setCompleter(m_nameCompleter);
connect(m_playersSelect->lineEdit(), &QLineEdit::textEdited, this, &ScorePage::nameSearchChanged);
```

and

```
void ScorePage::nameSearchChanged(const QString &text)
{
    QStringList possibleNames;
    for (const QString &name : m_availableNames) {
        if (checkMatch(name, text)) {
            possibleNames << name;
        }
    }
    m_matchingNames->setStringList(possibleNames);
}
```

Most probably not the most prerformant solution, but it works :-)

One then can also connect to `QCompleter::activated()` to process what has been chosen from the list and e. g. do a `QComboBox::setCurrentIndex()` or such.